# Refresh or reload Internet Explorer object in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, webforms

I'm working on a way to fill in online forms using data from an Excel Spreadsheet. I'm using the VBA Modules in Excel to do so.

The steps are as follows:
1) Navigate to page
2) Fill in details
3) Click "Continue" to continue to the next page
4) Fill in more details
5) Click "Save" to save the page

Here is the code:

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
  'Header Start
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim ROW As Integer
  Dim MAXROW As Integer

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  MAXROW = 3
  ROW = 2
  'Header End

  'Step 1 Navigate to the page
  IE.Navigate *PAGE_1_URL*
  IE.Visible = True

  While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
  Wend
  'Step 1 Ends

  'Step 2&3 Fill in the details and click "continue"
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDPaymentMode").Value = "18"
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDPaymentDate").Value = Cells(ROW, 1).Value
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDBusinessUnit").Value = "104"
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDAmountPaid").Value = Cells(ROW, 2).Value
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_ContinueButton__Button").Click

  While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
  Wend
  'Step 2&3 Ends (IE moved to page 2)

  'Step 4&5 Fill in more details and click "Save"
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_BankChequeOrOtherRef").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 3).Value
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDRemarks").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 4).Value
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_SaveButton__Button").Click
  'Step 4&5 Ends

End Sub
```

I did step 1 to 3 fine. However, when it comes to step 4, I get an error. The error is: Runtime error 424 Object required. I am aware that this means that the Module is unable to locate the elements in step 4.

The error is at exactly:

```
IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_BankChequeOrOtherRef").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 3).Value
```

Before the process has to be terminated.

To debug whether the code in step 4 has any problem, I took it out and ran it separately. I took the entire section of Step4&5 and header out and make it navigate to the 2nd page instead.

Like so:

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim ROW As Integer
  Dim MAXROW As Integer

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  MAXROW = 3
  ROW = 2

  IE.Navigate *PAGE_2_URL*
  IE.Visible = True
  While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
  Wend

  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_BankChequeOrOtherRef").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 3).Value
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDRemarks").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 4).Value
  IE.Document.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_SaveButton__Button").Click

End Sub
```

And it worked.

I have no idea what is the problem. I'm guessing that all the elementID was loaded at the start or something and that the page 2 IDs were not loaded?

Does anyone know the source or solution to this problem? Thank you.

P.S. All names element ID are copied and pasted from the source code of the webform and should be correct.

Edit:
I have updated the issue in a comment below.

Edit2: Tried the exact same code on a win10 machine with excel 2016. Code worked perfectly. Thanks for all the help provided.

Comment: It is typical good practice in web scripting to wait until the object is found rather than just 'Happy Flow' to the end of your program. This could include outright Waits(then test for objects), or my preference is to wait for Object existence). Web page reading always needs to consider web devs change pages, and there is connectivity issues sometimes.

Comment: I usually have a function something like `WaitForObject(idOrPath as string, ie as InternetExplorer) As Boolean`. Then the function can deal with different instructions to find an object in the `ie.Document` Object. Typically a loop with trying to find the HTMLElement or root that I'm interested in reading, and then going ahead and reading all other Elements on the page that I 'expect' to be there.

Comment: Is there a particular way to wait for everything on the page to be loaded before searching for IDs? I thought that `While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4    DoEvents  Wend` did just that but I might have been mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the code to:

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
  'Header Start
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim DOC As Object
  Dim ROW As Integer
  Dim MAXROW As Integer
  Dim SAVEBUTTON As Object
  Dim COUNTER As Integer

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  Set SAVEBUTTON = Nothing
  MAXROW = 3
  ROW = 2
  COUNTER = 0
  'Header End

  'Step 1 Navigate to the page
  IE.Navigate "*WEBSITE*"
  IE.Visible = True

  While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
  Wend
  'Step 1 Ends

  Set DOC = IE.Document

  'Step 2&3 Fill in the details and click "continue"
  DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDPaymentMode").Value = "18"
  DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDPaymentDate").Value = Cells(ROW, 1).Value
  DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDBusinessUnit").Value = "104"
  DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDAmountPaid").Value = Cells(ROW, 2).Value
  DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_ContinueButton__Button").Click
  'Step 2&3 Ends (IE moved to page 2)


  While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or SAVEBUTTON Is Nothing
    DoEvents
    If Not IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
        IE.Refresh
    End If
    Set DOC = IE.Document
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SAVEBUTTON = DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_SaveButton__Button")
    COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
  Wend


  'Step 4&5 Fill in more details and click "Save"
  DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_BankChequeOrOtherRef").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 3).Value
  DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDRemarks").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 4).Value
  DOC.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_SaveButton__Button").Click
  'Step 4&5 Ends

End Sub
```

Found out that this snippet is not refreshing the page even though it is supposed to.

```
If Not IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
        IE.Refresh
    End If
```

Is it possible that the object is dropped halfway?

Occasionally the code works when visibility of IE is turned off, but it works like once every hour or something before the exact same error pops up.

The page I am accessing seems to use ASPX and generates the page base on a database, no idea if this will help.

Edit: Tried the exact same code on a win10 machine with excel 2016. Code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try... (not tested)

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
  'Header Start
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim Doc As Object
  Dim ROW As Integer
  Dim MAXROW As Integer
  Dim ContinueButton As Object
  Dim SaveButton As Object

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  MAXROW = 3
  ROW = 2
  'Header End

  'Step 1 Navigate to the page
  IE.Navigate PAGE_1_URL
  IE.Visible = True

  While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or ContinueButton Is Nothing
    DoEvents
    Set Doc = IE.document
    Set ContinueButton = Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_ContinueButton__Button")
  Wend
  'Step 1 Ends

  'Step 2&3 Fill in the details and click "continue"
  Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDPaymentMode").Value = "18"
  Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDPaymentDate").Value = Cells(ROW, 1).Value
  Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDBusinessUnit").Value = "104"
  Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDAmountPaid").Value = Cells(ROW, 2).Value
  ContinueButton.Click

  While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or SaveButton Is Nothing
    DoEvents
    Set Doc = IE.document
    Set SaveButton = Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_SaveButton__Button")
  Wend
  'Step 2&3 Ends (IE moved to page 2)

  'Step 4&5 Fill in more details and click "Save"
  Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_BankChequeOrOtherRef").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 3).Value
  Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_PAYDRemarks").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(ROW, 4).Value
  SaveButton.Click
  'Step 4&5 Ends

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried your code and the same error occurred. Only this time it is at `Set SaveButton = Doc.ALL("ctl00_PageContent_SaveButton__Button")` that is in the while loop.

Comment: What that error says? Make sure you referring to the correct element on the page.

Comment: The error is "The error is: Runtime error 424 Object required. "

The name of the element is correct. However, the elements in the page might have been generated after the page is loaded or something. I've tried to use OnError to forcefully detect when the element is loaded, however, it seems that excel VBA cannot detect the newly loaded elements even though the page has finished loading in the IE.